# Email alert limit for external email ids

Tags: email, governorlimits, limits, email-alert

The limit for Email alerts via workflows is 1000 per licence per day. But does this apply only for internal users, or also email alerts to external email ids? I could not find any clarification in the documentation which would explain this. Does the emails to external email ids count towards this limit, or is there any other limits for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit applies to both internal Ids and external email addresses. However, it's important to recognize that this limit only applies to certain situations. 
The following items don't count against the workflow email limit:

- Approval notification emails
- Task assignment notifications
- Lead assignment rules notifications
- Case assignment rules notifications
- Case escalation rules notifications
- Force.com sites usage alerts

Also, be aware that if you send an email alert to a group, every recipient in that group counts against your daily workflow email limit.

See [Daily Limits for Email Alerts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/limits_email_workflow.htm) for more.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was having doubts as it was not mentioned in the limits whether mails to external email ids count against this or there is any other limit which applies.